# Merging mismatched row size data from different sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

scoured the internet. **Sample Sheet provided** [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uT_ULQiR1Eb88uhSrWYSZUxtI5Y5k0Ft0gBVVFGtt0U/edit#gid=132692984).
I have two sheets, a Purchase and Sold Sheet.

The'Purchases' sheet that has three columns:

```
ID    Purchase Date    Total
 4    12/6/2020        $100.00
 3    12/7/2020        $50.00
 2    3/1/2020         $25.00
```

My second Sheet is 'Sold' sheet has three columns:

```
ID    Sold Date         Total
 3    12/7/2020         $200.00
```

The **desired output on Sheet 3** should look like:

```
Quarter    Purchase Total    Sold Total
2020-Q4    $150.00           $200.00
2020-Q1    $25.00            $0.00
```

Using Named Ranges Sheet 3, I'm able to do these individually:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({query({YEAR(Purchases_PurchaseDate) & "-Q" & ROUNDUP(month(Purchases_PurchaseDate)/3,0), Purchases},"Select (Col1), sum(Col2) where (Col1) is not null group by (Col1) order by (Col1) DESC label (Col1) 'Quarter', sum(Col2) 'Purchase Total'")})
```

and a few columns over:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({query({YEAR(Sold_SoldDate) & "-Q" & ROUNDUP(month(Sold_SoldDate)/3,0), Sold},"Select (Col1), sum(Col2) where (Col1) is not null group by (Col1) order by (Col1) DESC label (Col1) 'Quarter', sum(Col2) 'Sold Total'")})
```

I'm not concerned about the named ranges, whatever way is simplest to yield the desired output or combine two queries that will not cause a Mismatched Row Size.  Please advise,

Comment: I can envision how this would be solved. However, there are still too many unknowns based on your post alone. The most efficient and effective way for those here to help you is if you share a link to a sample spreadsheet (e.g., one that has all the sheets and data that you show/explain in your post. If you choose to share such a link, be sure when creating the link to set the "Share" permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Hi there, Please Advise - I've added a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uT_ULQiR1Eb88uhSrWYSZUxtI5Y5k0Ft0gBVVFGtt0U/edit

Comment: Before we attempt to reinvent the wheel, see if player0's updated solution works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new sheet ("Erik Help") using a different formula from player0. You'll find that in A2:

`=QUERY({FILTER({YEAR(Purchases!B2:B) & "-Q" & VLOOKUP(MONTH(Purchases!B2:B), {1, 1; 4, 2; 7, 3; 10, 4}, 2, TRUE), Purchases!C2:C, Purchases!C2:C^0, IF(ROW(Purchases!A2:A), {0, 0, 0},)}, Purchases!B2:B<>""); FILTER({YEAR(Sold!B2:B) & "-Q" & VLOOKUP(MONTH(Sold!B2:B), {1, 1; 4, 2; 7, 3; 10, 4}, 2, TRUE), IF(ROW(Sold!A2:A), {0, 0},), Sold!C2:D, Sold!D2:D^0}, Sold!B2:B<>"")}, "Select Col1,  SUM(Col2),  SUM(Col3),  SUM(Col4),  SUM(Col6),  SUM(Col5) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 DESC LABEL Col1 'Quarter',  SUM(Col2) 'Tot. Purch $',  SUM(Col3) 'Tot. Number Purch.',  SUM(Col4) 'Tot. Sold $',  SUM(Col5) 'Tot. Fees',  SUM(Col6) 'Tot. Number Sold'")`

I also placed a cumulative total formula above all of that, in Row 1 (formula in A1), as well as some standard formatting and custom CF rules for row-by-row banding.

Comment: This was incredible useful. For anyone else curious, the additional tab Erik created was much cleaner. For anyone interested, If you need to add an additional columns in the second filter where you have more than 4 columns, instead of  Sold!C2:D, go with YourSheet!D2:F, for example, and update the first IF(ROW(YourSheet!A2:A, {0,0,0}

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A7:C12, IFNA(VLOOKUP(A7:A12, E7:H12, {2, 3, 4}, 0))})
```

[image]

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({query({YEAR(Purchases_PurchaseDate) & "-Q" & ROUNDUP(month(Purchases_PurchaseDate)/3,0), Purchases},"Select (Col1), sum(Col4), count(Col4) where (Col4) is not null group by (Col1) order by (Col1) DESC label (Col1) 'Quarter', sum(Col4) 'Total Purchased', count(Col4) 'Number of Items Purchased'"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(query({YEAR(Purchases_PurchaseDate) & "-Q" & ROUNDUP(month(Purchases_PurchaseDate)/3,0), Purchases},"Select (Col1), sum(Col4), count(Col4) where (Col4) is not null group by (Col1) order by (Col1) DESC label (Col1) 'Quarter', sum(Col4) 'Total Purchased', count(Col4) 'Number of Items Purchased'"), query({YEAR(Sold_SoldDate) & "-Q" & ROUNDUP(month(Sold_SoldDate)/3,0), Sold},"Select (Col1), sum(Col4), sum(Col5), count(Col4) where (Col4) is not null group by (Col1) order by (Col1) DESC label (Col1) 'Quarter', sum(Col4) 'Total Sold', sum(Col5) 'Total Fees', count(Col4) 'Number of Items Sold'"), {2, 3, 4}, 0))})
```

Comment: your solution uses the contents from already queried output on the same sheet. I'm trying to create the output from the Purchases & Sold Sheet only. Much appreciated,

Comment: @fuzzie answer updated. use 2nd fx. see your sheet

Comment: Thank you for this.  Using the updated query I could not yield the results. The first query returned the output of the first sheet, but the second query would only yield the first column, thus ignoring the additional columns in the second query's select.